# Updating a Neural Network input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I trained an 4 inputs by 1 output NN for 1 month and then the same NN was upgraded to become 5 I by 1 O. Should I repeat the training with the new configuration or I can still use the old training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If remaining 4 inputs still represent the same thing, you do not have to start from scratch. Instead, add new neuron in the input layer, and edges between it and hidden units. Initialize them as usually, but **leave remaining weights**. In other words - you are using your previous network as a starting point of the optimization. It should converge way faster, and in general be better, if you do not have access to historical data anymore (or you do not have time to retrain everything).

Answer (score 2):

You'll almost definitely need to repeat the training, unless you can feed your five-input NN to your trained 4-input NN, in which case you might be able to get away with less. It depends on exactly what the new variable represents.